# Cannot login properly in Grails

Tags: grails, spring-security

I've a grails application using Grails 2.3.9, and the Spring security plugin.

When I login to my page, the request is redirected to /[context]/grails-errorhandler, with the text:

```
Sorry, you're not authorized to view this page.
```

But when I access manually to /[context]/ , I can access to the website without problems!

The log says this:

```
intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor Previously Authenticated: <my authentication token>@20870684

hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl getReachableGrantedAuthorities() - From the roles [<many roles>] one can reach <same roles>] in zero or more steps.

support.XmlWebApplicationContext Publishing event in Root WebApplicationContext: org.springframework.security.access.event.AuthorizationFailureEvent[source=FilterInvocation: URL: /grails-errorhandler]

access.ExceptionTranslationFilter Access is denied (user is not anonymous); delegating to AccessDeniedHandler

<more stacktrace>
```

Did you know what kind of problem is this?

Comment: can you provide the configurations for spring security.  I can only guess but "/" is not secure but when you login, it tries to access a page which is secured...only a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, but I don't know why this happens...

In the UrlMappings, I added the next rule:

```
"404"(controller:'error', action:'notFound')
```

(I have an "ErrorController").

But I don't know why this change causes the problem with spring security, but if I remove it, the application works without problems.

Thanks! Specially to getbuckts for the comment :)